# Correct way to initialize Enums inside a class constructor

Tags: c#, enums, initialization

I could be looking at Enums in the wrong way but want to make sure I have the right theory in how to use them.

Say we have an enum called Colour.

```
enum Colour { Red, Green, Blue };
```

Red Green and Blue are represented by there 0-255 values.
I'm trying to initialize this enum inside a class shape and I'm not really sure how to go about it.

```
public class Shape
{

    Colour colour;

    public Shape(Colour c)
    {
         //Some attempts at initialization.


         //Treating It like an object
         this.colour = 
            c{
                255,255,255
            };

         //Again
         this.colour.Red = c.Red
         this.colour.Blue = c.Blue
         this.colour.Green = c.Green

         Colour.red = c.red?


         }
    }
}
```

I'm probably way off in terms of how I'm thinking about enums. Can anyone give me some pointers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, you might want Colour to be `struct` instead of an enum. In C#, enums are single-valued constructs, but you have three values (red, green, and blue). Here's what I might do instead:

```
public struct Colour 
{
    private byte red;
    private byte green;
    private byte blue;

    public Colour(byte r, byte g, byte b) 
    {
        this.red = r;
        this.green = g;
        this.blue = b;
    }
}

public class Shape
{
    public Colour Colour { get; private set; }

    public Shape(Colour c)
    {
        this.Colour = c;
    }
}
```

And then when you're creating your shape objects:

```
var shape = new Shape(new Colour(203, 211, 48));
```

---

**EDIT**: As Chris pointed out in the comments, you could simply use the `System.Drawing.Color` struct provided by the framework. The example above would be simplified to:

```
using System.Drawing;

public class Shape
{
    public Color Colour { get; private set; }

    public Shape(Color c)
    {
        this.Colour = c;
    }
}

var shape = new Shape(Color.FromArgb(203, 211, 48));
```

Comment: out of interest if going this way why not use the Color class? That seems to have the same functionality and then a bit more and will be much more interoperable and much less like reinventing the wheel...

Comment: @Chris: That's a good point, and I think you're right. I've updated my answer with an example using the built-in `System.Drawing.Color` struct.

Answer (score 1):

An enum is very much like a Type (or Association) table in a relational database. It is a set list of options so you can constrain a value. Think of an enum as a "pick list" perhaps, if you are not as well versed with relational databases. Enums give us a small, finite list of choices for a variable whereas the underlying type (int, byte, etc) is much larger.

The normal method to accomplish what you are trying is to test the enum value and then set up your object:

```
switch(c)
{
   case Colour.Red:
        //Set up red shape here
        break;
   //etc ...
}
```

Comment: adenum: Actually, you can specify the underlying type for an enum (`enum MyEnum : int16 {...}`) but this is discouraged (see msdn about enum for details). When you do not specify values, your enum members automatically are given int values 0, 1, 2, ...) (exception: "flags" enums start with 1, 2, 4, ...)

Comment: @eFloh: I have, in samples, coded flags with explicit 1,2,4 ... n values, but this is merely to explicitly show what the framework does implicitly. It is a great way to teach how bitmasks work. ;-) In business code, I agree 100%, however. I can't think of a reason to set numbers on an enum (not saying there aren't any valid reasons, just none that I can think of off hand).

Comment: Oh, one simple reason for setting numbers on enums: Consider having a web service that sends some kind of numeric return codes. You may locally define an enum with known codes to be able to write self-explanatory code (e.g. ´if ((WsCode)wsResultcode == WsCode.NoDataFound) { ...}`) But when you have the service definition under your control, you should definitely use the enum values directly and keep in mind that WSDL enums do *not* carry their value, but only the name, so "casting to int across a web service" is a bad idea...

Comment: @eFloh: Kudos. I like that idea. Was not thinking SOA at the time I added the comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.colour = Colour.Red; // or Colour.Green or whatever
```

`this.colour` is of type `Colour` and can take only one of the three values. Think of `Colour` as a type like `Integer` but it can take one of only three values while `Integer` can take any one of the values in `Integer.MIN_VALUE..Integer.MAX_VALUE` range.

If you are trying to construct an `RGB` colour out of it then this is not the right approach. In that case you are looking for a class named `Colour` which has different values for its `red, green and blue` components.

Answer (score 0):

Your enum `Colour` does not have properties for each enum value you have defined. The values Red, Green, and Blue are values that your enum **could be**.

You want to do something like `this.colour = Colour.Red` to set your `colour` variable to the value of red. Then, later in the code if you only wanted to trigger some code based on whether or not the value was red you could do something like:

```
if(this.colour == Colour.Red)
{
// Do red specific logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd be best off with an immutable struct:

```
public struct Colour
{
    private readonly byte red;

    private readonly byte green;

    private readonly byte blue;

    public Colour(byte red, byte green, byte blue)
    {
        this.red = red;
        this.green = green;
        this.blue = blue;
    }

    public byte Red
    {
        get
        {
            return this.red;
        }
    }

    public byte Green
    {
        get
        {
            return this.green;
        }
    }

    public byte Blue
    {
        get
        {
            return this.blue;
        }
    }
}
```

You'd initialize it as such:

```
Shape shape = new Shape(new Colour(104, 255, 67));
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a [type-safe](http://www.javacamp.org/designPattern/enum.html) enum is what you are looking for. They allow for much richer behaviour that standard enums.

```
public sealed class Colour
{
  public int RedComponent { get; private set;}
  public int GreenComponent { get; private set;}
  public int BlueComponent { get; private set;}

  public static readonly Colour Red = new Colour(255,0,0);

  private Colour(int red, int green, int blue)
  {
    RedComponent = red;
    GreenComponent = green;
    BlueComponent = blue;
  }
}
```

You can then have a method `Foo(Colour c){//Do something with c.RedComponent etc.}` and call `Foo(Colour.Red)`

You can even compare values as per a normal enum:

```
Bar(Colour c)
{
  return c == Colour.Red;
}
```

Comment: If you wanted custom colours you would make the constructor public, however in that case new Colour(255,0,0) == Colour.Red would return false as they would point to different instances.

Answer (score 0):

If colour is your enum then all you need to do in your constructor would be to say:

```
this.colour = c;
```

However, I'm a little confused and worried by your comment on "Red Green and Blue are represented by there 0-255 values". most colours will have a value for each of the red green and blue so you don't want just an enum.

An enum can be most easily thought of by analogy to a drop down box. There are a set of fixed values and your choice has to be one of those and no other. There may be a value behind the dropdown but usually you jsut want to know if the dropdown says "Red" or not, not what the value behind it is. The reason for this is that usually with Enums you are just going to say "If (colour=Colour.Red) then....".

What you are doing sounds a lot more like the .NET Class Color (named by the americans which might be why you didn't find it if this is what you want). This has properties for R,G,B as well as a bunch of Static properties that will return predefined instances of the Color class (eg Color.Red) would return an instance of Color with appropriate RGB set.

So I think you may have got the wrong end of the stick on Enums and possibly what you want here is the Color class.

The last thing you might be wanting is to have some kind of Factory class that does something like:

```
public Color CreateColor(Colour colEnum)
{
    switch(colEnum)
    case Colour.Red:
    return Color.Red;
    etc.
}
```

(apologies for confusing names and using Color and Colour)

This can ensure that you get colours based on your enum and only the colours defined in your enum are creatable in this way.